# Is $PROGRAM_NAME same as $0 in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is $PROGRAM_NAME same as $0 in ruby?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From ruby 1.8's code in svn trunk:

```
rb_define_hooked_variable("$0", &rb_progname, 0, set_arg0);
rb_define_hooked_variable("$PROGRAM_NAME", &rb_progname, 0, set_arg0);
```

So, yes, they should be the same.